# My class refuses to apply its rules to lists

Tags: css, class, inheritance

I have an `.active` class to apply to `li a` for the current page.

But it keeps being overrode by my styling the main `nav` `div`.

```
#nav ul li a:link, #nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #BBBBBB;
}

#nav ul li a:hover, .active, #nav ul .active a:link, #nav ul .active a:visited {
    border-bottom: red solid 2px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I've tried a few variations on the second rule to try and dethrone the first, but none seem to work. (I didn't have the id in originally, but I know that id is a step above class in the cascade).  Maybe I'm missing something really basic, or maybe my first rule is foolishly over specific? (I always seem to be running into this sort of problem with links, specifically)

Comment: You should post your HTML; it's equally important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have markup like this:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">foo</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Your CSS appears to work fine.

See http://jsfiddle.net/X7eAw/1/

You may need to add

`#nav ul li.active a`

to force specificity if the `active` class is not being applied. That selector is probably overkill however.

*assuming* you have the `active` class on your `li` element. If you are applying `active` to the anchor, then the rule should be: `#nav ul li a.active:link`

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent a style from getting overriden in CSS by using !important tag:

```
#nav ul li a:hover, .active, #nav ul .active a:link, #nav ul .active a:visited {
    border-bottom: red solid 2px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: It's almost always better *not* to use `!important`, as it usually indicates a flaw in your CSS/HTML.

Comment: It can also be used to work around a bug/flaw in a browser: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349259, http://jafferhaider.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/fix-for-the-firefoxcss-one-page-printing-bug/